# Getting twitter updates into sharepoint

Tags: web-part, development

I would like to get the twitter updates from a user account onto my SharePoint site. Please suggest me how to use that functionality.

Answer (score 7):

- Use the RSS Viewer webpart and link it to the Twitter Account.
  OR
- Use DataView Webpart for advanced UI customization , with RSS feed as Datasource

Answer (score 4):

Woody Windischman has a [good example](http://thesanitypoint.com/archive/2009/03/05/binary-free-sharepoint-twitter-search-web-part.aspx) on his blog, it's based on search but could easily be tweaked to pull user updates.

Answer (score 2):

Depending what you're trying to accomplish, you can also use the Twitter Widget:
[Twitter Profile Widget](http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile)

If you look at the code, the following piece of code:

```
render().setUser('TwitterUSER').start();
```

Is what sets the user - You can have your user save his twitter name in a custom list, and simply use a little bit of XSLT within a Data View WebPart to pull it out and output the user within the twitter widget code.

Answer (score 1):

I would just say use the Twitter Widget.

http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets

Only downside is that there is a rate limit. So this may not work well if you have a lot of traffic.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting

Answer (score 1):

On a related note, for anyone with Server using the User Profiles and Activity Feed, it is possible to create a custom listner that can pull twitter posts into the Activity Feed.

Here is a sample project from MS that outlines the creation of a custom listner:  http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/activityfeedsconsole